# Hadoop:No logs available for container

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am learning Hadoop , now I meet a problem when Single Node Setup.
I want to see JobHistory on the web page,but after i click [logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ7TY.png) what i can see is only ["No logs available for container container_1541377958924_0001_01_000001"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQIRH.png)  , i don't know how to solve it.

these are my configurations:

mapred-size.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>hadoop000:10020</value>
    <description>MapReduce JobHistory Server IPC host:port</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>hadoop000:19888</value>
    <description>MapReduce JobHistory Server Web UI host:port</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir</name>
    <value>/history/done</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir</name>
    <value>/history/done_intermediate</value>
</property>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>


<property>
    <name>yarn.log.server.url</name>
    <value>hadoop000:19888/jobhistory/logs/</value>
</property>
```

forgive my poor English , thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see in the WebApp the logs from Hadoop jobs you need to start the JobHistory Daemon in addition to enable aggregation logs.

Try:

`$ ./sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh # OR mr-job-history-daemon.sh 
$ stop-yarn.sh && start-yarn.sh`